# Add Facebook SDK in your eclipse project

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cocos2d-x, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to add Facebook sdk in eclipse(I'm using cocos2d-x) , following this guideline

[image]

I'm confused where to add "repositories{ mavenCentral() }" as eclipse project don't have build.gradle.

I've also tried implementing this one :

> https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/
>
> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-vNi1W4fco

but when I import Facebook sdk in eclipse, it still give errors.

[image]

If anyone have idea, please help. Thanks!

Comment: The error by itself is not FB related. You should find and add support-annotations-????.jar lib to your project. This JAR lib could be found in SDK folder. Mine are here d:\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-annotations\

Comment: Should I add it in libs folder?

Comment: Yes, you should add it to libs folder of your project. Another thing: Eclipse is not an google's official IDE nowadays (but it was) so I recommend you to use Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

There are following step to import Facebook:

1. Download latest fb sdk and extract it.
2. import it into eclips as android project.
3. If it is showing any error regarding android support then include **"android-support-v4.jar"** also **bolts-android-1.1.2.jar** in your lib folder

> If you are using fb sdk in your cocos2d-x project make sure your project and fb sdk in same directry.

Answer (score 1):

Change Your Project Target SDK to 19 And Go to >> Project Property>> Java Compiler>> Uncheck to defaults java Version that's 1.7 or 1.6

It work Fine in My Case..